# wso2 API Manager, java Restfull Endpoint can't be found when calling the API through the swagger

Tags: wso2, endpoint, api-manager

I created an API with WSO2 API Manager adding my own java Restful Service as Endpoint. Testing the service endpoint worked fine.
[image]
I subscribed to the API properly but when invoking the API with the swagger it returns the following body content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.45 - Error report</title>
<style type="text/css">
H1 {
font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
color:white;
background-color:#525D76;
font-size:22px;
} 
H2 {
font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
color:white;
background-color:#525D76;
font-size:16px;
} 
H3 {
font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
color:white;
background-color:#525D76;
font-size:14px;
} 
BODY {
font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
color:black;
background-color:white;
} 
B {
font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
color:white;
background-color:#525D76;
} 
P {
font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
background:white;
color:black;
font-size:12px;
}
A {
color : black;
}
A.name {
color : black;
}
.line {
height: 1px; 
background-color: #525D76; 
border: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HTTP Status 406 - Not Acceptable</h1>
<div class="line"></div>
<p><b>type</b> Status report</p>
<p><b>message</b> <u>Not Acceptable</u></p>
<p><b>description</b> <u>The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.</u></p>
<hr class="line">
<h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.45</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

An application/xml media type is supposed to be returned!

Here is the screen shot of my swagger after calling the api

[image]

Here is the response when calling the service directly from the browser

[image]

I have also changed the response media type to application/json but it still did'nt worked too.

Can someone please help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you have `message` part at the end of both `endpoint` and actual `request`. That makes the underneath call becomes

```
http://localhost:8080/messanger/webapi/messages/messages/
```

which is an invalid URL.

The solution is simple. Remove the `messages` part from the endpoint URL.

i.e. Endpoint URL should be `http://localhost:8080/messanger/webapi/`

Comment: Thank you for your proposition. i have changed my endpoints to http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/ but i am still  getting the same Error Code.

Comment: Please enable wire logs and update your question with the logs.
http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html